# History of Latin sinus cardinalis

Tags: terminology, math-history

Who introduced the term sinus cardinalis?
I do not mean the abbreviation sinc, which was introduced 1953 by Woodward.

Comment: Before the close votes accumulate, I'd like to point out that this question is right in the middle of what the [tag:math-history] tag is for: "Use this tag for questions concerning history of mathematics, historical primacies of results, and evolution of terminology, symbols, and notations. Consider if History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange is a better place to ask your question." A question can hardly be off-topic when there's a tag precisely for questions like that.

Comment: I suppose Woodward did, when he introduced the abbreviation in [this paper](http://www.norbertwiener.umd.edu/crowds/documents/Woodward52.pdf) in 1952. How can he introduce the abbreviation without the full expansion of it? He just doesn't mention it in written form, that's all.

Comment: No he didn't. And it's very unlikely, that a modern English speaking author would introduce a Latin phrase. And then without mentioning it immediately proposes an abbreviation.

Comment: I had the suspicion that Euler did. But couldn't find it in the 'Introductio'.

Comment: Also asked at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/7474/72 , where there is an answer.